# Optionally return empty object

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out how I can optionally return an empty object in Typescript, I have found it surprisingly difficult to do this.

As a contrived example lets say we have:

```
interface Human {
    name: string,
    race: string,
    city: string
}

interface Alien {
    name: string,
    species: string,
    planet: string
}

type TransformedData = HumanAndroid | AlienPredator;

type HumanAndroid = {
    make: string;
    model: string;
    intelligence: number;
} | {}

interface AlienPredator {
    name: string,
    finishingMove: string,
    planet: string
}

export const transform = (
    input: Human | Alien,
    type: 'human' | 'alien' = 'human'
): TransformedData => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'human':
            return transformHuman(input as Human);
        case 'alien':
            return transformAlien(input as Alien);
    }
};

function transformHuman(human: Human ): HumanAndroid {
    if (human.name === '') {
        return {}
    }
    return {    
        make: "2020",
        model: "MDX343",
        intelligence: 100
    }
}

function transformAlien(alien: Alien): AlienPredator {
    return {    
        name: 'majinbuu',
        finishingMove: 'roundkick',
        planet: 'mars'
    }
}
```

In the first return statement in `HumanTransform` function:

```
if (human.name === '') {
    return {}
}
```

I can change the return statement to anything, say:

```
if (human.name === '') {
    return {"randomKey": 4}
}
```

And it won't cause an error. How can I disallow anything but an empty object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you say your function returns `x`, then you can return anything that's also a subtype of `x`.

You can explicitly disallow additional properties using something like this:

```js
type R = {
  [k: string]: never
}

function foo(): R {

  return {a:1}; // error

}
```

Which solves your problem. From a pure library design perspective I would suggest you return `null` instead of an empty object though.

Comment: When returning an object literal, Typescript normally does excess property checking, even if there is not strictly a type error. The real question is why Typescript doesn't do excess property checking in this case, and how to get it to.

Comment: The reason Typescript doesn't do this is because there might be a difference between what you return, and what you intend to be part of the API. The only way you can make it do this is by declaring your returned value explicitly as a type in the function body, or use my snippet.

Comment: I took your advise on just returning null, which sounds right.